# Breaking a LaTeX environment across pages - the smart way

Tags: latex

I am using the [exercise](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/exercise/) package to display exercises in a book. I have redefined some commands like this, which basically adds some space, a pencil, and two hrule's before and after the exercise:

```
\renewcommand{\ExerciseHeader}{\vskip 1em\hrule\vskip 1em\centerline{\textbf{\large\smallpencil
\ExerciseHeaderNB\ExerciseHeaderTitle%
\ExerciseHeaderDifficulty\ExerciseHeaderOrigin\medskip}}}
\makeatletter\def\endExerciseEnv{\termineliste{1}\@EndExeBox\vskip .5em\hrule\vskip 1em}\makeatother
```

Now this works, but there's a small problem:

There are situations where only the \hrule ends up being at the bottom of a page, and the rest of the exercise goes on the next page. There is also the opposite behavior: the entire exercise is on one page, except the \hrule in "endExerciseEnv", which is flushed to the next page.

How do I force the top hrule come?

- either together with the header of the exercise (caption, title, whatever not) and at least say 5em or so of "exercise text" (so it doesn't look ugly),
- OR be flushed altogether, with the entire exercise?

A similar question for the bottom hrule:

How do I force it have at least 5 em of "exercise text" in front of it on the visible page where the hrule itself goes to? (or the beginning of the Exercise environment, whichever comes first - as it's the case if the environment is not higher than 5em)

**Addendum**

I have asked in the past LaTeX questions like this and I've got answers which required me to do stuff manually, like "insert a \vskip here and there" or such.

Let me be clear: This is a book, there are a lot of exercises, and I *need* it be done "automatically", by going the proper way of redeclaring commands & co.

Comment: Generally, when you get an answer about how to do it manually, you have the option of wrapping the result up in  `\newenvironment` or similar. Moreover, if the result is more than a trivial incantation there is something to be said for making it into a full blown extension package. Search on "LaTeX for class and package writers". Of course, it is better when someone has done the work for you. That's where many of the packages on CTAN come from...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TeX can insert page break before any glue, for example `\vskip 1em`.

Make some changes:

1) You write `\vskip 1em\hrule\vskip 1em`
Replace it with

```
\vskip 1em\hrule \nobreak \vskip 1em
```

2) You write `\vskip .5em\hrule\vskip 1em`
Replace it with

```
\nobreak\vskip .5em\hrule\vskip 1em
```

You also can insert `\goodbreak` to show good point to break the page.
This good point can be inserted before and after your excersise.

1) `\goodbreak\vskip 1em\hrule \nobreak \vskip 1em`

2)  `\nobreak\vskip .5em\hrule \goodbreak \vskip 1em`

Answer (score 1):

Kudos to myself: https://ctan.org/pkg/needspace

> Pro­vides com­mands to dis­able page­break­ing within a given
>   ver­ti­cal space. If there is not enough space be­tween the com­mand
>   and the bot­tom of the page, a new page will be started.

Comment: The link is broken. It says *"Not Found. The re­quested URL /tex-archive/help/Cat­a­logue/en­tries/needspace.html was not found on this server."*

Comment: @PeterMortensen Thanks. Fixed.